# Express - how to calculate avg requests per minute

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, pm2

I'm looking for a simple way to know how many records are being created by my Node.js analytics service. I came across [average-requests-per-minute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/average-requests-per-minute) Express middleware, but the author says:

> Disclaimer: it's very simple, trivial, keeps things in memory, and does not verify all the parameters. It is not tested well (yet), so use at your own risk.

That makes me not event want to use that module in development...

#### What is a simple way to calculate average requests per minute in an Express app, managed by pm2, ran on EC2?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [pm2 custom metrics](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-metrics/).